# android - bottom behavior child views changes doesn't always work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-design

In my activity I have map with markers. When user clicks marker, it shows details about that place with bottom sheet.

When views filled with data about place for the first time, it works properly. But after hiding bottomsheet, then showing it after click again it doesn't work properly:
TextView saves old height (`view.invalidate()` doesn't work).
`viewGroup.addView` method doesn't work (calling `viewGroup.removeAllViews()` before adding, but it keeps old height and adding views doesn't work).

But when I change views data without hiding/showing bottomSheet, all things work properly. Like changing for the first time.

I saw other other weird behaviors too, while debugging: I had linearLayout which had 4 relativeLayouts (with textView and imageView inside). When I changed visibility(gone/visible) of one/two they would overlap to each other, even though linearLayout had vertical orientation. But not always, just like above: first time works okay, other times if I change views when bottomSheet is not visible doesn't work properly (as described), but when bottomBehavior is visible and if I change views it works okay (like first time).

If I'm not mistaken, it's because of bottomsheet. Becuause, I didn't see like this behavior of views on Android before.

My code:

```
mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                    hidePlaceDetails();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });

/**
 * Show bottom sheet with given place details and start load route
 *
 * @param place the place
 */
private void showPlaceDetails(Place place) {
    placeTitleView.setText(place.getTitle());
    placeCategoryView.setText(place.getParentTitle());

    placeInfoGroup.removeAllViews();
    addPlaceInfo(R.drawable.ic_info, place.getDescription(), null);
    addPlaceInfo(R.drawable.ic_place, place.getAddress(), null);
    addPlaceInfo(R.drawable.ic_phone, place.getPhoneNumbers(), null);
    addPlaceInfo(R.drawable.ic_language, place.getWebsite(), null);

    Photo photo = place.getPhoto();
    if (U.isEmpty(photo.getImagePath())) {
        U.hideView(placePhotoView);
    } else {
        U.showView(placePhotoView);
        int proportionalHeight = U.calculateProportionalHeight(
            screenSize[0] /*screenWidth*/,
            photo.getWidth(),
            photo.getHeight(),
            800 /*maxHeight*/);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            proportionalHeight
        );

        placePhotoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        ImageUtils.networkImage(this, photo, placePhotoView, null, U.imagePlaceholder());
    }

    U.view(placeDistanceProgressView, true); //showView
    U.view(placeDistanceView, false); //hideView
    if (mMap.getMyLocation() != null) {
        Waypoint myLocation = new Waypoint(mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude(), mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude());
        Waypoint destination = new Waypoint(place.getPosition().getLongitude(), place.getPosition().getLatitude());

        getAndDrawRoute(place, myLocation, destination);
    }

    int thirdScreen = screenSize[1] / 3;
    mMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, halfScreen);
    isShowingPlaceDetails = true;
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(halfScreen);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}

/**
 * Hide bottom sheet and add markers
 */
private void hidePlaceDetails() {
    mMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    addMarkers();
    isShowingPlaceDetails = false;
}

/**
 * @param icon            icon res
 * @param title           title
 * @param onClickListener nullable
 */
private void addPlaceInfo(
    @DrawableRes int icon, String title, @Nullable View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    View root = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_map_bottom_sheet_row, null);
    ImageView iconView = ButterKnife.findById(root, R.id.place_icon);
    TextView titleView = ButterKnife.findById(root, R.id.place_title);
    iconView.setImageResource(icon);
    titleView.setText(U.notEmpty(title) ? title : Html.fromHtml(String.format("<i>%s</i>", "None")));

    if (onClickListener != null) {
        root.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }
    placeInfoGroup.addView(root);
}
```

activity*.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_appbar"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        ...
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_map_bottom_sheet"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

...
```

layout_map_bottom_sheet.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/content.margin">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/content.padding.big"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/content.padding.big"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/content.padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/content.padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place.title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text.line.space"
        android:textColor="@color/text.color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text.xlarge"
        tools:text="@string/lorem.place.title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place.category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text.line.space"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/content.padding.small"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/content.padding.small"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text.medium"
        android:textColor="@color/text.secondary.color"
        tools:text="@string/lorem.short"/>

    <include layout="@layout/divider"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place.distance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/content.padding.small"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/content.padding.small"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="@string/lorem.place.distance"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/place.distance.progress"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content.padding.small"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/content.padding.small"/>

    <include layout="@layout/divider"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/place.infos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/place.photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@drawable/sample"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Screenrecord: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5up2CgQawSDbUZtQ2h1VDBWbms/view?usp=drivesdk

It was hard for me explain this, but the issue drove me mad for a couple days. I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: did you solve this issue? It seems I have the same or a very similar problem. It happens when I use removeAllViews. If I do not use removeAllViews, then it works.

Comment: @peshkira nope. I gave up

Comment: oh, noes :/ ... it seems to be a layout lifecycle problem with the bottomsheet, because the debugger says, the views are inserted for me. But I do not see them.

Comment: @peshkira for me, using or not using removeAllViews didn't matter. Did you try xml screenshot? If yes, can you see them there?

Comment: Yes. I just tried it. Interestingly enough, the support lib converts all other TextViews to AppCompatTextView, but the dynamically added TextViews are still TextViews. Also they have 0 height and width.

Answer (score 3):

I solved a similar issue with the following workaround.

In my `BottomSheetCallback` I added the following:

```
behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onStateChanged(final View bottomSheet, int newState) {
    switch (newState) {
      case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
      case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
        bottomSheet.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            bottomSheet.requestLayout(); // this seems to fix it.
          }
        });
        break;
      case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
        // remove the views here with removeAllViews();
        break;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

  }
});
```

It is still not perfect, because the new Layout takes some time to render and the views pop in with some lag. But better than nothing.

Also, there seems to be a bugfix for this within the latest support lib 24.0.0 if you already support target 24

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205226

Comment: I did try invalidating layout. But it didn't work. But I didn't try invalidating at expand state with post running. I changed my layout structure so I can't test whether your solution works. I will accept it as solution if other users vote up your solution. Thanks!

Comment: great. Please note, that `invalidate` is not the same as `requestLayout`. Invalidate only marks a layout as dirty, whereas requestLayout schedules a new layout pass.

Comment: This solution is working fine for me. But i have seen lagging in view while collapsing the bottom sheet.